# How to pronounce/read 00s?

Tags: pronunciation

I have been reading answers to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/347852/grokking-java-culture-why-are-things-so-heavy-what-does-it-optimize-for). Someone has written this phrase:

> In the late 90s/early **00s**, Java became an extremely popular language
>   for server-side business applications

I know we read *90s* as *nineties*. But I am not able to read the bold text above. How do we pronounce it? Something like *zero zero iz*?

Comment: If you were to read it as separate digits, it would be *"zero zeroez"* - the final "zeroez" is just one syllable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contextually, whenever decades are referred to by their last two digits, they refer to decades that have occurred in the last 100 years. As you've already noted, *90s* is read as "nineties", *80s* is read as "eighties" and so on. However, unlike those decades, [there isn't a clear consensus as to what to call the *00s*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000s_(decade)#Name_for_the_decade).

Some of the terms used include the "noughties" (deriving from the British name for the digit 0), "aughts" (an archaic word meaning "nothing at all", referencing the double 00s) as well as "two thousands" (deriving from the fact years from 2000-2009 were often referred to as "two thousand and *number*").

Personally I read it as "two thousands", but as far as I know there's no clear accepted standard.

Comment: Interesting to know there is not a consensus about it even among the native English speakers. I thought it is something too simple and evident for "others". Thank you for the useful feedback.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ As a matter of interest, how are they saying it in French? *Les (années) soixantes...(années) quatre-vingts-dix, et ...*?

Comment: The position is not much easier for the decade we are currently in. Will we, looking back, talk of "the tens", "the teens", or what?

Comment: No, you should write *Les années soixante* because numeral adjectives do not take *s* . We also write *Les années quatre-vingt* [but there are situations where you must write *quatre-vingtss* ... better to ping me in a chatroom otherwise people will flag our comments as they are not related to English (I am not French, I am Algerian, moved to France when I was 30 years old) @WS2

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ But you haven't told me what, in France, they are calling the 00s?

Comment: @WS2 I forgot about it, sorry, but in French we do not reason the same way as in English. In French we say simply *Les années deux milles* to refer to 00s.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Perhaps that's the answer then, *the two thousands*! Let us be guided by France.